# plot created from generic_ews() function cannot be exported using png()

Tags: r, plot, time-series, export, png

I'm creating a for loop which will iterate through multiple time-series data into the function `generic_ews()`. This function outputs a dataframe as well as a plot. As the for loop iterates through each time-series data, I would like for the plot to be saved as a png (or any form for the matter). But, it only returns a blank png. So far, only manually saving the plot directly from the plot window works, but this is unfavorable as I will be iterating through 80+ time-series. Here is the code:

```
library(earlywarnings)

data(Nile, package = "datasets")

png(file = "test.png")
generic_ews(Nile)
dev.off()
```

I've tried editing the function directly to include `png()` and `dev.off()`. Instead of png(), I've used other forms (jpeg, pdf, tiff), as well as using `ggsave()`. All have given me a blank png.